# Reading a text file from ADLS Gen2 by spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, streaming, databricks, filestream

I'm reading a text file from adls gen2 using Databricks. This is my code.

I can read successfully, but when I'm defining the query and writing the stream, I'm getting an error: I could not find the ADLS gen2 token. Could you please provide me with a solution to perform spark streaming on a text file?

I have tried to pass the SAS token even though it is not able to stream the file instead it is able to stream the directory.

```py
file_path = "adl://<account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>/<path>/*.txt"

streaming_df = spark.readStream \
.schema(schema) \
.text(file_path) 

query = streaming_df_transformed.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.format("console") \
.start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: where you tried to pass sas token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question instead of using `adl` filesystem
you can use `abfss`.

`abfss://<container_name>@<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/`

And you can configure the `SAS` token using below code.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "Your_SAS_token")
```

[image]

Now for text files, you need to give directory for readstream and to filter out only `.txt` you can give
`pathGlobFilter` option while reading.

Code:

```
file_path = f"abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/databricks/text/"

streaming_df = spark.readStream.schema(schema).option("basePath", file_path)\
    .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.txt").text(file_path + "*")

display(streaming_df.select("*","_metadata.file_path"))
```

Output:

[image]